# ClassNotFoundException in com.amazonaws.demos.polly.PollyDemo

Tags: java, amazon-polly

I'm new to Maven and the AWS SDK. So I installed both and updated my Java SDK. Double checked all required path and classpath settings. 
The AWS Polly manual (page 119 in the pdf) presents a demo code example, to test Polly.
Being in this for the very first time, I tried this example (pom.xml and PollyDemo.java). Calling Maven as written in the manual, I receive the ClassNotFoundException for PollyDemo (classpath to com.amazonaws.demos.polly package has been set). 
With over 10 years Java experience I feel like a newbie.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `aws-java-sdk-polly` dependency into your `pom.xml`
 file and update the project, you can find dependency below:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-polly</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.77</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.soundlibs/jlayer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.soundlibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jlayer</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1-1</version>
        </dependency>
```

for more you can refer below link :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/de_de/polly/latest/dg/examples-java.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/examples-java.html

Comment: Thanx. The pom.xml example has these dependencies.

Comment: Studying Maven's manual I see that a new project hasn't been created (calling mvn archetype:generate and so on). I'll try this way, because possibly the code example assumes this step.

Answer (score 0):

The example can be run if: AWS credentials are created and setted (1), a new project is started by creating an empty directory (e.g. 'my-app'),
opening a shell in 'my-app' and running the command 'mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.amazonaws.demos.polly -DartifactId=polly-java-demo -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false' (2), and finally replace both the existing 'pom.xml' and hello world java file with the ones in the example (3).